# Does stream reused allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, stream

Here is my code.

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"D:\test\1.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                        writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    }
                }

                // I reused this stream again and below code just a sample.
                // It would get exception
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    //System.ArgumentException: 'Update mode requires a stream with read, write, and seek capabilities.'
                }
            }
```

Is this exception caused by 'stream cannot be resued in C#' ?
If the answer is yes, any office documents can let me take a reference ?

Thanks in advance, it's appreciate if your guys can provide some help.

Comment: Have a look at the ZipArchiv constructor overloads. There is something that will help you in this case

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ZipArchive` assumes lifetime control of the `Stream` it is handed, and disposes it when *it* is disposed. To avoid this, set `leaveOpen` to `true` in the constructor overloads. However: you will also probably need to *rewind* the stream between usages, so you'll need `zipToOpen.Position = 0;` between the two `using` blocks. Anecdotally, it does seem *unlikely* that `1.txt` is a zip file, but... I guess it could be!

Comment: Thank you very much, one comment of yours better than I study ten years.

Comment: @feichenwang a `Stream` is *in principle* just a mechanism to provide a sequence of bytes - you read data, and it may eventually run out of data to give you. Once you've read some data, you're now further into the stream, and reading it a second time will either give you different data, or an EOF indication. If you want to read the original data *again*, you need to explicitly tell it to go back to the start (note: not all streams have a concept of seek - you can't seek on a socket, for example). Think of it like rewinding a VHS tape (if you know what one of those is!)